# Insert Select, 2 distinct 1 non-distinct

Tags: mysql, select, join, insert

```
    pantodata table:
    year    starID    agentID
    1957     0         100
    1958     1         100
    1959     2         101

    star table:
    starID   starName   role   agentID
       0      Stu       rom     100
       1      Bla       fay     100
       2      ian       lay     101

    contract table:
    year      starID    agentID
```

I already have a table where a star is referenced to the each agent.  A star has a unique star ID, whereas an agent may have many stars.  Within the contract table I'm trying to reference each star and agent to a year which has been specified within pantodata.  What would the potential solution be to use the star table(prior relation) or a solution just using the pantodata.
What one would be more efficient in the long run?

Solutions I have tried:

```
    -#1062 - Duplicate entry '8' for key 3 
    INSERT INTO Contract (year, starID, agentID)        
    SELECT DISTINCT year, starID, agentID
    FROM pantodata

    -#1062 - Duplicate entry '1957' for key 1
    INSERT INTO Contract (year, starID, agentID)        
    SELECT DISTINCT p.year, s.starID, s.agentID
    FROM pantodata p, star s
```

Both of these don't work as year & starID are distinct but agent isn't.

Comment: Contract Table e Pantodata table have the same structure....

Comment: Pantodata has more data but I didn't feel like it was necessary to input it